# Launch the Details page for a specific contact in android default contact application from our app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, google-contacts-api, contactscontract

I have created a list of contacts that exists in my phone, sync to all accounts(i.e. SIM1,SIM2, Phone, Google account). Now on the click of my list item I want to open the default contact app's detail page of the user when a given user is selected(or clicked from my list).

Also is there a way through which I can add my apps icon on the opened detail page of the user so that when I click on the icon I should be able to open my app's given activity.